# How should I pick a way to make ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, passport.js

There seems to be so many choices and I don't have time to read into depth about all of them.

I started using

```
$.ajax({...})
```

but now that I use React this is the only place in my app that I use jQuery.  I'm basically sending the whole library to the client for this one call.

I then thought about using

```
window.fetch
```

However this was not workable because **passport** does not authenticate this request.  I liked it because it was native JavaScript.  I don't understand why it is not authenticated by passport code running on my server like the **jQuery** ajax call was.

I also looked at this library briefly as another way.

[github - request](http://%20https://github.com/request/request)

Looks like it might be overkill to make an authenticated ajax request.

Could I just user a native ajax request.  Would this be authenticated?

This would be a 4th way - [Native Ajax Request - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

I normally adopt for native / minimalist solutions even if it means having to write a bit more code.

Comment: Something wrong in your use of `fetch()` config if it is not working. Provide example of working `$.ajax` along with `fetch()` that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Passport needs to confirm the session by using cookies but Fetch  API doesn't send cookies by default, I think you should add the `credentials` flag to your request like this:

```
const options = {
   credentials: 'include'
};
fetch(url, options).then(...);
```

read more about it here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)